# ReadProcessMemory just returns chunks

Tags: c#, encoding

I'm trying to read out Memory from a specific process. To get started, I used this Tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670373/Csharp-Read-Write-another-Process-Memory this is working fine so far for Notepad, but now I wanted to to the same with the Open Office Writer (swriter).

This would work as well, but I just get chinese signs. I read on another Thread, that you have to convert the Strings to another Format.

My procedure is looking like this at the moment:

```
    public string ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr procHandle, int position)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[24];

        DllImports.ReadProcessMemory(procHandle, position, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);

        var regex = new Regex(@"^\w+$");

        result = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && regex.IsMatch(result, 0))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unicode: " + result);
        }

        result = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && regex.IsMatch(result, 0))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ANSI: " + result);
        }

        result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && regex.IsMatch(result, 0))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ASCII: " + result);
        }

        result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && regex.IsMatch(result, 0))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UTF8: " + result);
        }

        return result; 
    }
```

I'm calling it just at every possible position for testing purposes.

```
        ProcessHelper p = new ProcessHelper();
        p.EnumProcessNames();

        var handle = p.GetProcessHandleByProcessName("swriter");

        Parallel.For(0, Int32.MaxValue, f => p.ReadProcessMemory(handle, f));
```

Sadly, I get really mixed results. Most of the Time the Output is looking like this:

> Unicode: 煱煱煱煱煱煱煱煱煱煱煱煱
>   ANSI: qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
>   UTF8: 444333344444444444444444
>   Unicode: ᡐᡐᡐᡐᡐᡐᡐἰᡐᡐᡐᡐ
>   UTF8: 444444444443344444444444
>   ANSI: 444444444433444444444444
>   ANSI: 443333444444444444444444
>   ASCII: 443333444444444444444444
>   UTF8: 443333444444444444444444
>   ASCII: qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
>   Unicode: ᡐᡐᡐᡐᡐᡐἰᡐᡐᡐᡐᡐ
>   ASCII: 444444444433444444444444
>   UTF8: 444444444433444444444444
>   ANSI: 433334444444444444444444
>   UTF8: qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
>   ANSI: 444444444334444444444444
>   Unicode: ᡐᡐᡐᡐᡐἰᡐᡐᡐᡐᡐὀ
>   Unicode: ᡐᡐᡐᡐἰᡐᡐᡐᡐᡐὀᡐ
>   Unicode: ᡐᡐᡐἰᡐᡐᡐᡐᡐὀᡐὐ
>   ASCII: 444444444334444444444444
>   ASCII: 433334444444444444444444
>   UTF8: 433334444444444444444444
>   Unicode: ᡐᡐἰᡐᡐᡐᡐᡐὀᡐὐ彟
>   Unicode: 煱煱煱煱煱煱煱煱煱煱煱q
>   UTF8: 444444444334444444444444
>   Unicode: 煱煱煱煱煱煱煱煱煱煱煱倀
>   ANSI: 444444443344444444444444
>   ANSI: 333344444444444444444443

And on the later Numbers, I just get:

> Unicode: 耇耇耇耇耇耇耇㠇㠸㠸㠸㠸
>   Unicode: ހހހހހހހ㠸㠸㠸㠸㠸
>   Unicode: 耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇
>   Unicode: ހހހހހހހހހހހހ
>   Unicode: 耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇
>   Unicode: ހހހހހހހހހހހހ
>   Unicode: 耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇
>   Unicode: ހހހހހހހހހހހހ
>   Unicode: 耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇耇㠇
>   Unicode: 耇耇耇耇耇耇㠇㠸㠸㠸㠸㠸
>   Unicode: ހހހހހހ㠸㠸㠸㠸㠸㠸
>   Unicode: 耇耇耇耇耇㠇㠸㠸㠸㠸㠸㠸
>   Unicode: ހހހހހ㠸㠸㠸㠸㠸㠸㠸
>   Unicode: ހހހހހހހހހހހ㠸

With the OllyDbg Tool, I can read the whole Memory without problems.

Am I missing something here? I didn't find another implementation of ReadProcessMemory except this one:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, int lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);
```

Comment: You cannot reasonably ignore the return value of ReadProcessMemory().  The process has 2 billion possible addresses, the vast majority of them contain nothing at all.  You'd have given up long before you had a chance to find something.  The odds that you'll actually find a string back are comparable to finding the proverbial needle in the haystack.  Get somewhere sane with error checking and VirtualQueryEx().

Comment: Well when I get the exact address via OllyDbg and read only this one, I get the Chunk as well, while OllyDbg reads it out correctly. So I guess there has to be done something special for parsing this?